# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function after refactoring from class to function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just refactored a legacy React 16.6.3 app from having a class-based `SearchBar` component to a function component like so:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const SearchBar = ({ onFormSubmit }) => {
  const [term, setTerm] = useState('');

  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    onFormSubmit(term);
  };

  return (
    <div className="search-bar ui segment">
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="ui form">
        <div className="field">
          <label>Video Search</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={term}
            onChange={(event) => setTerm(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

I do not see anything wrong with my code, it should work as expected even if I have yet to refactor the `App` component from class to function component. I am importing the `SearchBar` like so:

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import youtube from "../apis/youtube";
import VideoList from "./VideoList";
import VideoDetail from "./VideoDetail";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { videos: [], selectedVideo: null };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onTermSubmit("JavaScript");
  }
```

What gives here, I cannot detect where I made the error. Here is the exact error:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
SearchBar
src/components/SearchBar.js:3
  1 | import React, { useState } from 'react';
  2 | 
> 3 | const SearchBar = ({ onFormSubmit }) => {
  4 |   const [term, setTerm] = useState('');
  5 | 
  6 |   const onSubmit = (event) => {
View compiled
▶ 22 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
src/index.js:5
  2 | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  3 | import App from './components/App';
  4 | 
> 5 | ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
  6 | 
View compiled
```

Comment: Also add how you're rendering the SearchBar component inside the App component please. Just saw your React version as well, pretty sure hooks weren't in React v16.6.3. Think they were added in v16.7, or maybe v16.8. Does upgrading your React version fix the error?

Comment: @Jayce444, go ahead and post your suggestion as an answer. I upgraded `react` and `react-dom` to `16.11.0` and the error went away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Daniels's comment, this was due to React being version 16.6.3, which was before hooks were supported. Upgrading `react` and `react-dom` to v16.11.0 fixed the problem